# Multi-module application and versioning strategy

Tags: java, git-flow, semantic-versioning, aws-service-catalog, maven-multi-module

I have a Spring boot application with several modules (I'm using Maven) and each module includes several other modules/libs (eg. for MongoDB, MySQL, ActiveDirectory etc.) and some of them are in common among these modules.

Eg.

```
Module A (API REST)
- include lib X
- include lib Y 

Module B (Batch Job)
- include lib X
- include lib Z

Module C (API REST)
- include lib X
- include lib Y
- include lib R
```

these (X, Y, Z) libs/modules are other maven modules not third part libraries that we can find on Maven Central Repository.

This is not a micro-services application as we usually intend and, at the same time, it's not a monolithic application but a sort of "macro-services" application.

I can release one these macro-modules independently (e.g. release a new version of Module A but not B).

Which is the best way to handle the versioning of all these modules?

Using the semantic versioning for each module/lib?

e.g.
I make a bug-fix on lib Z than Module A and B will be released as 1.0.1?

So:

```
lib Z (1.0.0 => 1.0.1)
Module A (1.0.0 => 1.0.1) because depends on lib Z
Module B (1.0.0 => 1.0.1) because depends on lib Z
```

But what the will be the version number of the entire application that I can define in the root POM.xml?

I'm asking this because we are using a GITFlow release branch strategy and AWS Service Catalog for the production release distribution.

A datetime versioning for the Service Catalog release could be useful in this case?

E.g.

```
lib Z (1.0.0 => 1.0.1)
Module A (1.0.0 => 1.0.1)
Module B (1.0.0 => 1.0.1)
```

Service catalog release 20230724 will contain all the modules reference through CloudFormation Stacks.

Or should I kepp using the semantic versioning even for the Service Catalog release?

In this case the version number for the Service Catalog (entire product) release which logic should follow?

E.g.

```
Bug fix on Module A => Service Catalog release 1.0.1 (because mod. A 1.0.1 - mod. B 1.0.0)
Feature improvement on Module B => Service catalog release 1.1.0 (because mod. A 1.0.1 - mod. B 1.1.0)
```

Pros and Cons of each versioning stragey?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: working with different versions will just make it more complex